# jQuery show a class and hide all others

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is what I would like to do:

I have this list HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class = "point">Point1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class = "point">Point2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class = "meanCurvature">mean Curvature 1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class = "meanValue">mean Value 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and a selector with several options.

Then I have a 
JS

```
if($("#selector").val() == "strain"){
  $(".point").show();
  $(".meanCurvature").hide();
  $(".meanValue").hide();
}
if($("#selector").val() == "curvature"){
  $(".meanCurvature").show();
  $(".point").hide();
  $(".meanValue").hide();
}
if($("#selector").val() == "average"){
  $(".meanValue").show();
  $(".meanCurvature").hide();
  $(".point").hide();
}
```

I would like to know: now I only have three class and it is handable, but is there a way to say "Show this class and Hide all other"?

Comment: `$('selector').show(); $('selector1, selector2, ...').hide();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest this if you have limited number of rows in your table.

```
if($("#selector").val() == "strain"){
  $(".point").show();
  $('td').not('.point').hide();
}
if($("#selector").val() == "curvature"){

  $(".meanCurvature").show();
  $('td').not('.meanCurvature').hide();
}
if($("#selector").val() == "average"){
  $(".meanValue").show();
  $('td').not('.meanValue').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the :not selector such as:

```
$("td:not(.classToActuallyShow)").hide();
```

Will select all the table data(td) elements and hide them, unless they have a specific class.

Comment: there is no `value` on a `<td>`

Comment: @charlietfl I used the value in exampe because his question has "($("#selector").val() == "strain")"

Comment: That is a separate condition ... likely for a `<select>`

Answer (score 0):

you may want something like this

```
if($("#selector").val() == "strain"){
  $(".point").show();
  $(".point").parent().siblings('tr').children('td').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would say

```
$("td").hide();
$(".desiredClass").show();
```

This will first hide all your table elements, then reveal the one you're interested in. However, I would also assign a class to your table, so you can avoid interfering with other tables on the page:

```
<table class="myTable">
...
```

and the javascript would then be

```
$(".myTable td").hide()
$(".desiredClass").show()
```

---

You could further improve this using advanced selectors

```
$(".desiredClass").show()
$(".myTable td:not(.desiredClass)").hide()
```

The above could would avoid any possible 'stuttering' by hiding and then revealing the desired element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not()` as [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_not.asp) or as a [method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_not.asp) to selects all elements except the specified element.
Another way would be use [multiple elements selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_multiple_sel.asp), like 
`$(".point, .meanValue").hide();`But it isnt reccomended if you have a lot of classes in this case.
Check this working example:

```js
$("#selector").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "strain"){
      $(".point").show();
      $("td:not(.point)").hide();
    }
    if($(this).val() == "curvature"){
      $(".meanCurvature").show();
      $(".point, .meanValue").hide();
    }
    if($(this).val() == "average"){
      $(".meanValue").show();
      $("td:not(.meanValue)").hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector">
    <option disabled selected>Select option</option>
    <option>strain</option>
    <option>curvature</option>
    <option>average</option>
</select>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class = "point">Point1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class = "point">Point2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class = "meanCurvature">mean Curvature 1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class = "meanValue">mean Value 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by showing all `td`s and then hide the ones that have other classes using `not()` function. Alternatively you can hid all `td`s and then show your selected class.

Before doing that, you need to convert your `selector` value to the desired class using a simple `switch`.

```js
function apply() {
  var selectedVal = $("#selector").val();
  switch (selectedVal) {
    case "strain":
      selectedVal = "point";
      break;
    case "curvature":
      selectedVal = "meanCurvature";
      break;
    case "average":
      selectedVal = "meanValue";
      break;
  }
  $("td").show().not("." + selectedVal).hide();
}
apply();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector" onchange="apply()">
<option>strain</option>
<option>curvature</option>
<option>average</option>
</select>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="point">Point1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="point">Point2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="meanCurvature">mean Curvature 1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="meanValue">mean Value 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can make it easier and get rid of the `switch` if you can change your `selector` values to match the classes:

```js
function apply() {
  $("td").show().not("." + $("#selector").val()).hide();
}
apply();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector" onchange="apply()">
<option value="point">strain</option>
<option value="meanCurvature">curvature</option>
<option value="meanValue">average</option>
</select>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="point">Point1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="point">Point2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="meanCurvature">mean Curvature 1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="meanValue">mean Value 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be combine all those classes  into one selector. Hide them all then filter the one you want to show based on a stored object that matches the value to the class

```
var classMatches ={
   'strain':'point',
   'curvature':'meanCurvature',
   'average': 'meanValue'    
};

var matchingClass = classMatches[$("#selector").val()];

$('.point, .meanCurvature, .meanValue')
    .hide()
    .filter('.'+ matchingClass ).show()
```